# In Outlook, can I add reminders by default for outgoing messages?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, reminder, sent-items

As a lawyer, I have to go into my Sent items and add reminders to follow up on a significant fraction of emails I send.  Obviously, this is inefficient, but worse, I occasionally forget and something doesn't get followed up on in a timely manner.

In an ideal world, a dialog would pop-up after each send, asking me if and when I want a reminder.

In a slightly less ideal world, a reminder would automatically get set on every email I send, which I would have to manually opt-out of.  This method also has the significant drawback of not allowing me to select the reminder time.

What is the best (or second- or third-best) way to accomplish what I want here?  I know some VBA and AHK basics.

Using Windows 10, Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2306 Build 16.0.16529.20226) 32-bit, in case it matters.

Comment: Anything can be done w/ a [macro](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=outlook+macros) in Outlook. You can either [write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/Concepts/Getting-Started/writing-an-outlook-macro) one or download them - **downloaded ones should _never_ be run until after visually inspecting their code** _(macros are the primary vectors of malware in Office)_. There is a slight learning curve to writing macros, but it can be understood in an hour w/ no prior experience. Due to your profession, you'll likely find other areas macros can help you in Outlook/other office programs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default reminder for all messages that you flag for yourself or for recipients. To do this, go to File > Options > Tasks and select the Default reminder check box. Then, choose the time interval that you want for the reminder.

You can also set a custom reminder for each message that you send. To do this, click on the Follow Up button in the Tags group on the Home tab. Then, click on Add Reminder and choose the date and time that you want for the reminder.

Comment: You mean `Set reminders on tasks with due dates`?  I think this doesn't really solve the problem because it requires me to set a due date on each outgoing message.